# How to connect to LocalDB in a .NET 5 project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localdb

I am writing a console application using .NET 5, and I am using a LocalDB instance (at least I hope that's the right terminology) to store the data that the application needs.  I can see the database (including both tables and all the data in said tables) in both the Server Explorer and SQL Server Object Explorer tabs of Visual Studio 2019, but the Data Sources tab the only thing that shows is the text "This window is not supported for the selected project."

The problem is, all the tutorials I've been able to find rely on that Data Sources tab.  From looking at other questions here on Stack Overflow, it looks to me like that tab is deprecated with .NET 5?  Am I correct?  And how would I write the code to access the database and perform CRUD operations without the Data Sources tab?

Sorry if this is a stupid question; this is my first time using LocalDB.

Comment: Can you explain what steps did you performed that results in the said behavior? Are you facing issue in writing code or in seeing data in DataSource tab? Did you read about ADO.NET ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thank you for the suggestion of using ADO.NET.  I'll have to read up about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SQL Server Object Explorer. If you right click on the database that you want to connect, you can see the properties, including connection string. If you have trouble with incorporating Connection string into your code - you need to show the code and the problem.

Whether Data Sources is deprecated or not, as you can see it is not supported for most projects (I think it's just for Windows projects - but I may be wrong). Anyway - you don't need it. And by the way - this approach works regardless of the database you use (LocalDB, SQL Express or regular SQL Server)